Spring WebClient retry fails because of ReadOnlyHttpHeaders
java           : 21
spring-boot    : 3.2.4
spring         : 6.1.5

What am I looking for?
I want to retry all my requests when the http response is not 2xx successful.
Problem: Retries tries to write on ReadOnlyHttpHeaders

The initial call made by the service reaches the target API and the target API returns a 4xx.

The 1st retry fails during the http request creation and does not reach the target API (UnsupportedOperationException).

The 2nd and last retry fails during the http request creation and does not reach the target API (UnsupportedOperationException).


It does not work because the during the retries, the http headers are ReadOnlyHttpHeaders and UnsupportedOperationException is thrown when Spring tries to set a content-length header value.
reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException: Retries exhausted: 2/2
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.retryExhausted(Exceptions.java:308)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST http://localhost:10000/ [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.core.Exceptions.retryExhausted(Exceptions.java:308)
        at reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec.lambda$static$0(RetryBackoffSpec.java:68)
        at reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec.lambda$null$4(RetryBackoffSpec.java:560)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.set(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:108)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.setContentLength(HttpHeaders.java:967)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.lambda$write$1(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:135)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)
    ... 43 more

The code
So, I made it this way:
public class ApiClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebClient apiWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:10000")
                .filter(filter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClient apiClient(WebClient apiWebClient) {
        return HttpServiceProxyFactory
                .builderFor(WebClientAdapter.create(apiWebClient))
                .build()
                .createClient(ApiClient.class);
    }

    private ExchangeFilterFunction filter() {
        return (request, next) ->
                next.exchange(request)
                        .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                            if (clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                                return Mono.just(clientResponse);
                            }
                            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Not 2xx"));
                        })
                        .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(2, Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
                ;
    }
}

The ApiClient is a simple Spring interface:
@HttpExchange("")
public interface ApiClient {
    @PostExchange("")
    Mono<Void> sendRequest(@RequestBody RequestDto request);

}

And it's called this way:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApiService {

    private final ApiClient apiClient;

    public Mono<Void> sendRequest(RequestDto request) {
        // Important: The retry may not appear here.
        // The method must stay as is. 
        return apiClient.send(request);
    }
}

One last mandatory thing
The retry must be set globally in the ApiClientConfiguration and must not be set in the ApiService. The method must stay as is, to stay "retry dependent free" for other usage of the package.
So, what am I doing wrong?
Obviously, I'm not doing it right and I may not be the only one trying to retry failed request. But I didn't find anything to make it work -_-'
I am aware the DefaultWebClient uses ReadOnlyHttpHeaders. Why does the retry tries to change the headers?
Is there a way to create the retry request more "writable"? Did I miss something about the WebClient or the Retry mechanism?

BTW, and for test purpose ONLY!: I tried anyway to test my retry feature by overwriting the Spring HttpHeaders class and bypass the read only problem: copy and paste in my project the class org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders and I overwrote the static methods public static HttpHeaders readOnlyHttpHeaders to return normal writable HttpHeaders instead of ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.
And it produced the expected result: 1 call reaching the target API and 2 retries reaching the target API, then stops with all http requests executed.
reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException: Retries exhausted: 2/2
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.retryExhausted(Exceptions.java:308)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST http://localhost:10000/ [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.core.Exceptions.retryExhausted(Exceptions.java:308)
        at reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec.lambda$static$0(RetryBackoffSpec.java:68)
        at reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec.lambda$null$4(RetryBackoffSpec.java:
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Not 2xx
    at com.example.config.ApiClientConfiguration.lambda$filter$0(ApiClientConfiguration.java:50)
...

